# What is the distribution of $\frac{(Y_1 - Y_2)^2}{2},$ where $Y_i$ are standard Normal and independent.

Tags: random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function

Determine the distribution of $\frac{(Y_1 - Y_2)^2}{2},$ where $Y_i$ ~ $N(0,1),$ and $Y_1,Y_2$ are independent.

I modelled the random variable in R and to me it seems like it's probably from a Gamma or Chi-squared distribution.

I genuinely have no idea how to calculate the distribution. I believe convolution will be needed but all the materials I have found online merely talk about the case where $Y_1+Y_2.$

Comment: $Y_1 - Y_2 = Y_1 + (- Y_2)$. Does that help? Also are you familiar with the definition of a $\chi^2$ random variable?

Comment: @jld It's the $^2$ part that I am having more trouble with rather than what is in the brackets.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: A reinforced hint:  Note that $Y_1-Y_2$ and $Y_1+Y_2$ have the same distribution.

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer this question as if it had been tagged with the `self-study` tag.

Hint: consider $Z = \frac{Y_1 - Y_2}{\sqrt{2}} \sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$. You are looking for the distribution of $Z^2$.